# Perpendicular lines

Tags: geometry

The lines CD and EF are perpendicular with points $C(1,2)$, $D(3,-4)$, $E(-2,5)$, and $F(k,4)$. Find the value of the constant $k$.

Comment: Please, show your work, what you know, what you have tried, &c. People won't do your homework for you here. It is expected you do something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The OP presumably does not know about vectors or dot products.  Here's the appropriate hint: What do you know about the *slopes* of perpendicular lines? Now can you do the problem?

Comment: The product of the gradients = -1. If a gradient of a line was 1/2, the perpendicular gradient = -2/1 = -2.

Comment: Yes. Good! So, you were right above, the line $EF$ has slope (gradient) $-1/3$. I missed that, sorry. So now use the definition of the gradient ... if you know $E$ and $F$ are on the line, find the gradient and solve for $k$.

Comment: tried plugging into y = mx + c and end up with 4 = -1/3k + 3 1/3

Comment: Your $3\ 1/3$ is wrong. It should be $13/3$ (better not to use mixed numbers). If you then solve for $k$, what do you get? But you don't need that. Just compute the slope using only the coordinates of $E$ and $F$.

Comment: How do you compute the slope? Struggling to get my head around it.

Comment: @Ed, how did you get the gradient of $EF$ in the first place? Didn't you say the gradient (slope) of $CD$ is $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{-4-2}{3-1} = \frac{-6}{2} = -3$. Then the gradient of $EF$ should be the *negative reciprocal*, so it should be $+1/3$.

Comment: I did Change in y/Change in x. I think its in that method I made the mistake though, as I had though the gradient was -1/3. I'll have a go with that. Thanks for all this help, first time I have ever used stack exchange, people are friendly.

Comment: Ed, when you're satisfied, please accept the answer, so that it will not stay on the "unanswered" list :) Keep learning!

Comment: Click the checkmark next to my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(2, -6)\cdot(k+2,-1)=0$.

Comment: so far, I think I have gradient of line EF which = -1/3.

Comment: I would find it useful for a nudge in the right direction, as I'm not sure where to start. It is homework

Comment: Two vectors are perpendicular iff their dot product (inner product) is $0$.